# Can a malicious Tornado Cash Relayer deanonimize users?

Tags: tornado-cash

Expanding on the question regarding [malicious Tornado Cash Relayers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94740/how-tornado-cash-relayer-trustless-protocol-works):
I'm trying to understand what protects users from malicious relayers connecting recepient address with IP address.

Imagine I operate a relayer. The relayer is a NodeJS http server. A user contacts me so that I execute the relay of the transaction.

I now know to connect the user's IP address with the transaction, and the recepient address.

A bit like malicious TOR nodes can eventually identify the original source of certain traffic.

Am I misunderstanding something?